# Last.fm Top Artists Api

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, aiohttp, last.fm

```
  @commands.command()
  async def np(self,ctx):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            params= {"api_key" : "censored",
            "user" : "ssj4abd",
            "period" : "overall",
             "limit" : 10,
             "method":"user.getTopArtists",
             "format":"json"}
            async with session.get(url="http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0", params=params) as response:
                resp = await response.read()
                print(resp)
```

I am making it so that it retrieves the top (1st) artist of a user, the reply is something really long which you can find [here](https://hastebin.com/uxibaqalin.rust). How do I retrieve/fetch only the `"rank" : 1` artist from all that mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're requesting a JSON response

> "format":"json"}

So this is what you get. To load it into a dictionary, use the `json` library

```
import json
jsonData = json.loads(resp)
```

Now, you can get the dictionary for the first artist via

```
topArtist = jsonData["topartists"]["artist"][0]
```

And from there, you can retrieve all the info, like the url

```
topArtistUrl = topArtist["url"]
```

---

```py
import json
@commands.command()
  async def np(self,ctx):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            params= {"api_key" : "censored",
            "user" : "ssj4abd",
            "period" : "overall",
             "limit" : 10,
             "method":"user.getTopArtists",
             "format":"json"}
            async with session.get(url="http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0", params=params) as response:
                resp = await response.read()
                jsonData = json.loads(resp)
                topArtist = jsonData["topartists"]["artist"][0]
                topArtistUrl = topArtist["url"]
```

Comment: [this](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/853563123147079691/855074157083099176/unknown.png?width=694&height=462) is the response, im confused on the extracting just the first artists name part

Comment: Well, if you want to get the name use `topArtist["name"]`. Or in short: `jsonData["topartists"]["artist"][0]["name"]`

Comment: @SSJ4ABD He's already given you an answer. Did you even read it? Replace `topArtistUrl = topArtist["url"]` with `topArtistName = topArtist["name"]`.